# Update using ranges provided in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have two table

```
**T1**      

object  Value   Calculated_Name 

AA       10 
BB       100    
CC       150    

**T2**  

R1  R2     Name

1   15      Z
16  130     w
```

I want to update Calculated_Name with name like this

```
**T1**      

object  Value   Calculated_Name 

AA       10        Z
BB       100       W
CC       150      Null
```

How I can do this?
PS: I have to run the command on SQL2000 or higher

Comment: What is the relationship between the two tables?  There's nothing obvious that relates them.  Without a relationship, you are pretty much looking at a straight UPDATE of T2.  `UPDATE T2 SET Calculated_Name='Z' WHERE object='AA'`...

Comment: No relationship ,
T2 is a reference table

Comment: is this homework? You stated `I have to run the command on SQL2000 or higher`. Well I'd hope so, and I'd hope it was 2008R2 or higher since it was just announced as end of life coming soon.

Comment: How do the two tables relate to each other? If they have a defined relation, you should be able to update from a simple join. In SQL2005+, you can join with a CTE if you need more complex processing from Table 1.

Comment: If there's no relationship, then you have no way of knowing which name from t2 should go in t1. This won't work.

Comment: No its not a homework :)

for example : with this reference table you can define grades for you customers

Comment: If you have a reference table, then you should have some sort of relation between the two. What is that relation? That is what you need to update `t1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have a relationship for update like if the value is between the range specified in the second table. Ranges also look inclusive from data.

```
update t
set 
Calculated_Name =Name
from
t1 t join
t2 p on t.value between r1 and r2
```

Comment: Also note that this would require that none of the ranges overlap.

Comment: @Shawn My assumption from the data.

Comment: Good assumption. Not good table design. But all too often, we work with what we got. :-/

Comment: @MohammadVakili Ok, so you DO have a relationship.  It will help next time you ask to be more clear about it in your question so those answering can more easily help.

Comment: @MohammadVakili Please, in addition to accepting this answer, update the question to clarify how these tables will relate to each other so there doesn't need to be an assumption.

Comment: I would add a note in your code stating that a fat-fingering admin can totally bork up your update here, causing a potentially invalid value to be updated in `t1`.

Comment: @MohammadVakili Maybe I can be more clear then, too.  A relationship does not have to be an implemented relationship in the db.  Even giving us a verbal idea of how the data relates would have helped.

Comment: @Shawn this way better for float range

Comment: What do you mean by "float range"?

Comment: @Shawn assume that T2 have value between 
1 and 9.9
10 and 115.2
115.3 and 1000

Comment: Gotcha. That's basically what you have in your example, just at a different scale. I just wanted to clarify that "float range" didn't have a special meaning. And by "bork up your update", I meant that if an admin accidentally enters a `t2` row with `r1=14` and `r2=17`, then it could potentially update a single `t1` row multiple times with an unexpected value.

Comment: yes, you alright . but the vales ranges checks in UI applications and this update should set the name